# Cant get all children using foreach and getcomponent

Tags: unity

I am trying to get the component `CheckPointEnemy` from each child object from an array of transforms, and then add those components to a list of CheckBehaviours. However I am only receiving the first component from the first child from the array of transforms:

```
public Transform[] enemies;
public List<CheckPointEnemy> enemiesToTrigger;

foreach (Transform child in enemies)
    {
       enemiesToTrigger.Add(child.GetComponentInChildren<CheckPointEnemy>);
    }
```

I imagine I should be using GetComponentsInChildren but I can not get the syntax correct.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you consider using AddRange if you want to use GetComponentsInChildren?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [reading the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html)?

It's not completely clear from your code what you are trying to accomplish. It would help if you explained where this code is located and why you're doing it this way. How does the `enemies` array get populated?

1. If you're trying to get the `CheckPointEnemy` components from all children of a particular component, use:

   `CheckPointEnemy[] enemiesToTrigger = GetComponentsInChildren<CheckPointEnemy>();`
2. If you're trying to find all `CheckPointEnemy` instances in the scene, use

   `CheckPointEnemy[] enemiesToTrigger = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<CheckPointEnemy>();`
3. If each child in the `enemies` list has multiple `CheckPointEnemy` children, use

   ```
   foreach (Transform child in enemies)
   {
      enemiesToTrigger.AddRange(child.GetComponentsInChildren<CheckPointEnemy>());
   }
   ```
4. If each transform in the `enemies` array has exactly one `CheckPointEnemy` component, and you're populating the `enemies` array from the Inspector, what you are doing is pointless. You can populate `enemiesToTrigger` in the Inspector instead.

Comment: It looks like they want to search the children of the `Transform` components in the `enemies` array, which doesn't seem to be shown in your code sample here.

Comment: @DMGregory The more I look at his code, the less I understand what he's trying to do, due to lack of context. Updated my answer to address all the cases I can think of, including the one that I think you have in mind.